# url contains spaces in django v3

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create my first django rest framework project and this is the scenario I'm stuck in.

In project's urls.py file I have this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # other paths
    path("api/", include("users.api.urls")),
    # other paths
]
```

While in users/api/urls.py file I have this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("user/", CurrentUserAPIView.as_view(), name="current-user")
]
```

This is the view (api/views.py):

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from users.api.serializers import UserDisplaySerializer


class CurrentUserAPIView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = UserDisplaySerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

What I can't understand is why If I go to localhost the list of urls look like this:

```
admin/
... other paths
**api/ user/ [name='current-user']**
... other paths
```

As you can see there is a space before "user" in the line between asterisks.
If I go to http://localhost:8000/api/user/ I receive this error: `'str' object is not callable` and I read it is related to a url configuration problem.

Comment: The space is not in the real urls, this is just how these are *formatted*.

Comment: Share your `views.py`

Comment: @GrandPhuba Ok, I added views.py code

Comment: can you show the full error? Will be great if you attach an image..

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error when I didn't append ending slash to the URL, i.e. http://localhost:8000/api/user

From you message it seems that slash is appended, but it can be affected via Django configuration, I suppose.